# Delete entire rows in excel sheet from a table using macro

Tags: vba, excel

i want to build a macro that delete rows from a table in an excel sheet based on an if statement that runs on all the rows from row number 2 to the end of the table - if the value in row i and column B equals 0 i would like to delete the entire row.

this is the code i wrote but nothing happens when i run it

```
Sub deleteZeroRows()

'loop for deleting zero rows
Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
Dim nLastCol, i As Integer

Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsCurrent = wbCurrent.ActiveSheet

Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Range("b2").End(xlDown).Select

For i = 2 To lastRow
    If wsCurrent.Cells(i, 2) = 0 Then
    wsCurrent.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Without looking at the code to closely if you delete rows like you do you have to go backwards in your loop. A second look tells me that the first issue is the line `lastRow = Range("b2").End(xlDown).Select` Do not use `Select` here

Answer (score 1):

**A faster method** to delete multiple rows from your worksheet is to store all the `Rows` that need to be deleted in a `Range`, using the `Union` function.

After you exit your `For` loop, just delete the entire rows `DelRng` at one command.

More notes in my code's comments below.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit  '<-- always use this at the top of your code

Sub deleteZeroRows()

Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, nLastCol As Long, i As Long
Dim DelRng As Range

Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook '<-- try to avoid using Active...
Set wsCurrent = wbCurrent.ActiveSheet '<-- try to avoid using Active...

With wsCurrent
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row in column B

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If .Range("B" & i).Value = 0 Then
            If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then
                ' add another row to DelRng range
                Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, .Rows(i))
            Else
                Set DelRng = .Rows(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

' if there's at least 1 row to be deleted >> delete all rows in DelRng at 1-line
If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

a "fast & furious" code:

```
Sub deleteZeroRows()
    With Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)) 'reference column B cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
        .Replace what:=0, lookat:=xlWhole, replacement:="" ' replace 0's with blanks
        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete ' delete rows where referenced range is blank
    End With
End Sub
```

which will also delete rows whose column B content is blank